# How to change layout definition runtime in TileRequestProcessor

Tags: java, struts, tiles

I have a scenario,
When request comes from IE browser then show `login` (which is default behaviour) and when it comes from Chrome browser then show `login_chrome` (Layout definition is in Tiles.xml like below)

```
<definition name="login" path="/login/login1.jsp"></definition>
<definition name="login_chrome" path="/login/login2.jsp"></definition>
```

And I have `CustomizedTileProcessor`

```
    public class CustomizedTileProcessor extends TilesRequestProcessor
    {
     @Override
   protected boolean processTilesDefinition(String pDefinitionName, boolean pContextRelative, HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse) throws IOException, ServletException
   {
      if (isChromeBrowser(pRequest))
      {
         pDefinitionName+="_chrome";
      }
      return super.processTilesDefinition(pDefinitionName, true, pRequest, pResponse);
   } 
}
```

**Note** : I don't want to put logic in JSP to select included JSPs as per condition.

Please help me and tell me which method of `TilesRequestProcessor` to override to change tile definition dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lot trial and error I got to know that I have to override `processForwardConfig` method of `TilesRequestProcessor`. And there I have to override the value of `path` value of `ForwardConfig` object to my new layout i.e. `login_chrome`.

Please see below code :

```
public class CustomizedTileProcessor extends TilesRequestProcessor
    {
     @Override
 protected void processForwardConfig(HttpServletRequest pRequest, 
       HttpServletResponse pResponse, ForwardConfig pForward) 
       throws IOException, ServletException
   {
      if(isChromeBrowser(pRequest))
      {
         ForwardConfig newForward = new ForwardConfig(pForward.getName(),
         pForward.getPath()+"_chrome", pForward.getRedirect(),
         pForward.getContextRelative());

         super.processForwardConfig(pRequest, pResponse, newForward);
      }
      else
      {
         super.processForwardConfig(pRequest, pResponse, pForward);
      }
   }
}
```